# How do I increment multiple attributes on a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to increment multiple attributes on the page with two objects. I have tried to use .split() like so

```
var words = $('.block').find('input').attr('js-data-reveals').split(',');
var num = 0;

words += '_' + num++

$('.block').find('input').attr('js-data-reveals', words);
```

Which returns:

```
js-data-box="TYPE_0,FONT_1"
```

I want to search the whole page for this attribute and increment each set. e.g

```
js-data-box="TYPE_1,FONT_1"
js-data-box="TYPE_2,FONT_2"
```

Comment: Seems like you should split your data into separate attributes, i.e., `js-data-box-type` and `js-data-box-font`

Comment: Yes that would be easier but that isn't an option i'm afraid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do a little of work with regex and jQuery, bellow a full working example:

```js
$(function(){
  $('.block').find('input').each(function(){
    var attrName = 'js-data-reveals';
    var $el = $(this);
    var attrs = $el.attr(attrName);
    var data = attrs.split(',').map(function(item){
      return item.replace(/\d+/, function(num){ return ++num});
    });
    $el.attr(attrName, data.join(','));
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body>
<div class="block">
  <input js-data-reveals="TYPE_1,FONT_1" />
  <input js-data-reveals="TYPE_5,FONT_2" />
 </div>
   <div class="block">
  <input js-data-reveals="TYPE_8,FONT_0" />
  <input js-data-reveals="TYPE_2,FONT_3" />
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use [String.split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), you create an array. You must loop through each item in the array. The correct way to do this would be to do this:

```
var num = 0; // Set counter to 0

var newString = string.split(",").map(function(item) { // Split the string by ',' then loop through each item, replacing it with the correct value
    return item + '_' + num;
}).join(','); // re-join the array of strings into a single string.
num++; // Increment counter.
```

EDIT:

It seems like you are asking for something else. In the case where you want to increment based on the current value, the correct way to do this would be to use a Regex as shown by Clieton. You still must use the [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function as split returns an array. The only difference is that you must use a regex to get the original number to increment.

Answer (score 0):

In case you wish to collect the attributes and store them with a unique counter.

```js
var num = 0;
var words = [];
var multiDimensional = [];
function CollectAttributes(params) {
    console.log("Print attributes Line by Line");
    $('.block').children('input').each(function () {
        var attributes = $(this).attr('js-data-reveals').split(',');
        var byLine = [];
        for(i = 0; i < attributes.length; i++){
            byLine.push(attributes[i]+ "_" + num);
            words.push(attributes[i]+ "_" + num);
        }
        multiDimensional.push(byLine);
        console.log(byLine.join()); // Result => Line by Line
        num++;
    });
    console.log("Print attributes all in one array");
    console.log(words); // Result => Basic array
    console.log("Print attributes in multidimensional array");
    console.log(multiDimensional); // Result => MultiDimensional array
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block">
  <input type="text" js-data-reveals="TYPE,FONT,ETC">
  <input type="text" js-data-reveals="TYPE,FONT,ETC">
  <input type="text" js-data-reveals="TYPE,FONT,ETC">
  <input type="text" js-data-reveals="TYPE,FONT,ETC">
  <input type="text" js-data-reveals="TYPE,FONT,ETC">
  <input type="text" js-data-reveals="TYPE,FONT,ETC">
  <input type="text" js-data-reveals="TYPE,FONT,ETC">
  <input type="text" js-data-reveals="TYPE,FONT,ETC">
  <input type="text" js-data-reveals="TYPE,FONT,ETC">
  <input type="text" js-data-reveals="TYPE,FONT,ETC">
</div>

<input type="button" value="Test" onclick="CollectAttributes(this);">
```